# TX recieved from subscribtion but not in Tx pool

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, txpool

I am running local Geth and I subscribe to pending transactions like this :

```
const subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions', (err, res) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
});

subscription.on('data', (txHash) => {
   blah blah
}
```

so I start receiving a stream of pending transactions.... however I caught few transactions which were broadcasted to the subscribtion, but are NOT in the tx pool pending or queued ... ( i get the pool content via txpool.content)

usually that is some old transaction from hours ago, which got stuck for low gas fee or whatsoever ...

why does this transaction not appear in the loca tx pool, BUT it gets broadcasted via the subscribtion?